# Why have a smaller fuse on input & larger on output on a power supply

Tags: power-supply

This appears to be a common practice in automation control panels - for example - on the power supply it has a 10A fuse on 120VAC input side & a 20A fuse 24VDC on the output. That power supply ratings are: 100-240VAC~5.6A in & 24VDC~20A out. I am just tying to understand the reasoning for this.

Answer (score 1):

Fuses work on \$i^2t\$ heating.

It's the current which causes the fuse to melt. If input requires less current and output gives more current, you will have to use a smaller current rated fuse at the input and a larger current rated fuse on the output. This is the usual case with step-down or buck converters.

However, if you are working with a step-up or boost converter, these will draw higher current on input and deliver lesser current (with higher voltage) on the output. In this case, you will find a larger current rated fuse on input and smaller current rated fuse on the output.

Answer (score 1):

Fuses are used to protect the wiring infrastructure. So, if your incoming 120 VAC cabling is rated continuously at higher than 10 amps then using a 10 amp fuse makes sense.

By the same token if the cables used on the outgoing supply (24 volts) are rated greater than 20 amps continuously then use a 20 amp fuse if the output line can drive more than 20 amps.

Fuses prevent fires; they don't protect electronics.

Answer (score 0):

Power is V*I, voltage multiplied with current. At the input side you have a high voltage, so you only need a small current. At the output side the voltage is reduced, meaning you need higher current to get the same power.

With the numbers from your supply: At the rated voltages the output can deliver a power of 24V * 20A = 480 W before the fuse may blow. For the input fuse this is dependent on the supply voltage. With 110V it will blow only when the power supply consumes 110V * 10A = 1.1kW.